# Editing partitions on USB drive disabled

Tags: windows, usb, partitioning, gparted, disk-management

I recently bought a 128GB USB drive, on which I'd like to make 4 partitions, but when I use Disk Management (Windows) and try to edit the main partition, the items in the list when right-clicked are disabled, so I can't edit the main partition. (see list on image below.)

When I use GParted (Linux) I can make the desired partitions and sizes. But Windows doesn't seem to like that: in Disk Management I can see all my partitions, but with no information displayed. Also right-clicking the partitions results in disabled functions and giving errors when asked to view the properties of that partition or to format it (see image). The error says that I have to reboot my PC in order to view the desired properties or to format it. Linux does seem to allow these partitions, which are functioning perfectly.

My last guess was using DISKPART, which was also no good. Also when running `LIST PARTITION` on my USB drive, the first partition, which Windows can read, is called `Partition 1`, but the other partitions are all called `0`.

All partitions are formatted in NTFS.

Does anyone have an solution to this problem?

[image]
<sup>**Disk Management**  (Click image to enlarge)</sup>

Comment: Windows can only use the first partition on removable drives. The bootice tools mentions this, see screenshot (the fourth one) at [Restore Your USB Key to its original state](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/restoring-your-usb-key-partition/)

Comment: @Zina That isn't quite right, because I can make a partition in my C drive, it works fine and it gets a drive letter (e.g. C: of D:)

Comment: Your C drive is on a USB drive? Or is it a internal/external HDD/SDD? Before posting I tried it on a 4GB USB Stick and got exactly the same behavior. Only the first partition was accessible from Windows. And I got the same error when trying to format any other. I am able to create multiple usable partitions on a external USB HDD.

Comment: My C drive is just a normal SATA drive, maybe that's why. Is it common that the USB-bus does not support partitioning? If so, is there any way around it?

Comment: Some manufacturers have tools for reformat. Be careful - you could make your device unusable. And it is not the USB bus, it is the device marked as such (it works for external HDD/SDD connected through USB). When you connect the USB Drive it will show as removable in disk management, on the other side a HDD in an external USB cage will be recognized as a e.g. basic disk and thus the possibility for more partitions. Some USB Keys have a CD-ROM emulated partitiion (which is read only) and a "data" partition.

Comment: Alright, thanks. So, if I'm not mistaken I have to use a third-party application to be able to partition my USB Drive?

Comment: If the "removable drive" bit is unchanged you will not be able to use any other than the first partition in Windows. As you said, Linux is fine with it. I would not dare to make the drive unusable. Is it a necessity for you to use more than one partition in Windows?

Comment: Well, there is a way to avoid using partitions, but it will end up very unorganised and messy, but if there is no other way around it, I'll have to.

Comment: -.- I have a 64 gb and 128 gb USB flash drive I partitioned, and use in Windows, at least once a week for imaging. Windows sees both partitions. The first is fat 32, the second is ntfs.

Comment: @CanadianLuke - could you share the make/model? What tool was used to partition them? How are they seen in Disk Management? I tried mine (4GB, 8GB, 64GB) and all were shown as removable drives without the option to shrink. I just tested my 8GB, deleted the part with diskpart and was able only to create one usable partition. So it seems dependent of the device. Tested on Windows 10

Comment: I had to use Debian Linux (at least, that's what I had available), and used `fdisk` (the Linux version) to wipe the partition table, and create a new one with the two partitions. I formatted the first as FAT32 in Linux, and left the second partition blank, and formatted it in Windows 7, using the Command Prompt

Comment: @CanadianLuke Well, I tried so, but I still can't format the unformatted partition...

Comment: When I get back to my computer at work, I'll backup my drive and try again